# Warning: LazyData DB of .... MB without LazyDataCompression set

Tags: r, devtools, r-package

I have run `devtools::check()` on my R package and obtained the following error:

> LazyData DB of 14.3 MB without LazyDataCompression set

One of the suggested solutions to this problem is to delete

> LazyData:true

from the description file. However, I need lazy loading for my datasets so that they get loaded into the environment upon installation.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 10):

One solution that I have found is the following:

Add

> LazyDataCompression:xz

to the description file.

PS: You might need to resave your data files using the xz compression using the function `resaveRdafiles()` of the `tools` package, as follows:

> resaveRdaFiles("data/yourDataFile.RData",compress="xz")

To check that the compression has been done successfully, use:

> checkRdaFiles("data/")

Comment: Of note, 'xz' packaging might not be optimal. In section 1.1.6 of "Writing R extensions", they suggest testing the alternatives ("bzip2, xz and the default, gzip") and even provide a convenience function which helps check which compression works best for you:
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Data-in-packages

Comment: For me it just worked to add the 

    LazyDataCompression:xz
line